# Add a space in string

Tags: python, string

How can I add a blank space in Python?

Ex.

```
print "How many times did " + name + "go here?";
```

will print:

```
How many times didnamego here?"
```

How can I add that space in?

Comment: Ignacio, can you please be more welcoming and useful, especially for an OP with 21 rep, so, obviously pretty new? Explain what you mean. e.g. Well, it looks like you already have a space to the left. I think your output should actually look more like "How many times did namego here". Is that correct?

Comment: @leoger: Please consider the vague possibility that you may be unusefully and mistakenly barking up the wrong tree. I think that the OP's print statement prints nothing, because it has a syntax error. Is that correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@yookd: Welcome to SO. This is not a real answer, just some suggestions for asking better questions.

Please check what you have typed before posting. Your `print` statement does not print what you say it does. *In fact it doesn't print anything, because it has a syntax error.*

```
>>> name = "Foo"
>>> print "How many times did " + name "go here?";
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "How many times did " + name "go here?";
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You are missing a `+` after `name`:

```
>>> print "How many times did " + name + "go here?";
How many times did Foogo here?
```

And even after fixing the syntax error it doesn't do what you said it does. What it does do is demonstrate one of the ways of getting a space (including it in the constant text).

Hint: To save checking, enter your code at the Python interactive prompt and then copy/paste the code and the results straight into your question, just as I did in this "answer".

Answer (score 12):

```
print "How many times did " + name + " go here?"
```

or

```
print "How many times did", name, "go here?"
```

or

```
print "How many times did %s go here?" % name
```

The preferred form in this simple case is the second one. The first uses concatenation (which is useful if you want more or less than one space between parts), the second uses the comma operator, which in the context of print joins the strings with a space, and the third uses string formatting (the old style), which should look familiar if you come from C, Perl, PHP, etc. The third is the most powerful form, but in this simple cases the use of format strings is unnecessary.

Note that in Python, lines do not need to be (and should not be) ended by semicolons. You can also use some of the [string justification methods](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.ljust) to add several spaces on either or both sides of the string.

Comment: Or ``print "How many times did {0:s} go here?".format(name)`` to use the [newer style of string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) introduced in Python 2,6.

Comment: @Blair tbh, I hate that style. I vastly prefer the C style.

Comment: Yeah, given my C background I usually default to the old style too. But the new style is the recommended method for Python 3 so it is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

With Python 3,

Using print concatenation:

```
>>> name = 'Sue'
>>> print('How many times did', name, 'go here')
How many times did Sue go here
```

using string concatenation:

```
>>> name = 'Sue'
>>> print('How many times did ' + name + ' go here')
How many times did Sue go here
```

using format:

```
>>> sentence = 'How many times did {name} go here'
>>> print(sentence.format(name='Sue'))
How many times did Sue go here
```

using %:

```
>>> name = 'Sue'
>>> print('How many times did %s go here' % name)
How many times did Sue go here
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print "How many times did ", name, "go here?"

>>> name = 'Some Name'
>>> print "How many times did", name, "go here?"
How many times did Some Name go here?
>>>
```